# Are users able to view source of web apps on ChromeOS?

Tags: google-chrome-os

If yes, is there a way to compile (NOT obfuscate) JS code for deployment in ChromeOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From quickly looking at the codebase using the Chromium.org Git browser, it appears that Google haven't gone out of their way to remove the "View page source" menu item from the version of Chrom(e|ium) shipped in Chrom(e|ium) OS.

Of course, there's nothing to prevent them from hiding the option in the UI, or removing the feature all together by `#ifdef`-ing it out, though.